# Dot Products and Linear Progamming

Tags: linear-programming, inner-products, duality-theorems

Let $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{m}$ and $w$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose that whenever $d \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfies $v_{i} \cdot d \leq 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m$, it also satisfies $w \cdot d \leq 0$. Prove that $w = \lambda_{1} v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_{m} v_{m}$ for some nonnegative real
numbers $\{\lambda_{i}\}_{i=1}^m$.

I have formulated the given constraint as a linear problem: $\max_{v_{i} \cdot d \leq 0 \text{ for } i=1,\ldots,m} w \cdot d = 0$. The dual will then be $\min_{\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_{j}d_{i} \geq d_{i} \text{ for } i=1,\ldots,m} 0$. How should I proceed and prove the proposition (all that I can gather is that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}w_{i}\geq1$), given that the dual is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the primal LP is to maximize $\sum_{j=1}^n w_j d_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n v_{i,j} d_j &\le 0 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$} \\
\end{align}
then the dual LP is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^m 0 \lambda_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^m v_{i,j} \lambda_i &= w_j &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag1\\
\lambda_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$}
\end{align}

We are given that $$\sum_{j=1}^n w_j d_j \le 0,$$  so the trivial feasible solution $d_j^*=0$ is optimal. By strong duality, the dual problem is also optimal, yielding the existence of the desired $\lambda_i$ via dual equality constraint $(1)$.

Comment: How did you get the $\lambda_{i}$ for the initial primal problem?

Comment: They are the dual variables, one per constraint. Similarly, in the dual problem, each $d_j$ is a dual variable for the corresponding equality constraint.

Comment: In that case, we can say that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} v_{i,j} d_j \le 0 \cdot \lambda_{i}$, right?

Comment: Well, only because $0 \cdot \lambda_i = 0$.  If the RHS were anything other than $0$, that wouldn't work.  What you can do is multiply *both* sides of the constraint by $\lambda_i$, yielding $\lambda_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{n} v_{i,j} d_j \le 0 \cdot \lambda_{i}=0$.

Comment: I think I'm having a hard time conbining your formulation with the common notion of converting primal problems to dual problems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program). How do the variables $\lambda_{i}$ feature in the constraints in the dual? Why would they be the coefficients (thank you for your great help)?

Comment: In the dual problem, $\lambda_i$ are the decision variables, like $y$ in the Wikipedia article, and $v_{i,j}$ are the constraint coefficients, like $A^T$ in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Then, why do the $d_{i}$ disappear in the dual problem?

Comment: They don't.  I put them in parentheses just to emphasize the correspondence, but I'll remove them now because they seem to cause confusion.

Comment: Where are the $d_{i}$ in the dual problem? Is the constraint $\sum_{j=1}^n w_j d_j \le 0,$ part of the dual problem or an extra consideration?

Comment: The $d_j$, like $x$ in Wikipedia, appear in the primal problem and not the dual.  The $\lambda_i$, like $y$ in Wikipedia, appear in the dual problem and not the primal.  The constraints for each problem involve only the variables for that problem.

Comment: I think I have gotten it. I had forgotten that the $v_{i}$ and the $w$ are constants, mistakenly assuming them to be the primal and dual variables' vectors. Thanks so much for the help!